# Linux command df extract "name" and "available space"

Tags: linux, shell, command, diskspace

How can extract only "name" and "available space" from df linux command.

Comment: This question might be off topic, but google still got me here ;)
Anyway, it seems newer df has --output option which does just what you want, so try `df --output=source,avail`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use...

```
df | tail -n +2 |  awk '{ print $1, $4 }'
```

...assuming you don't want the headers too. If you do, remove the `tail`.

We are piping `df`'s output into `tail`, where we cut the first line off (the headers), and then pipe that into `awk`, using it to print the first and fourth columns.

Comment: Hey Thanks for this.
for specific reasons, I dont want to use awk, any other approach we have ?

Comment: @Aryan Do you have a technical reason why?

Comment: Actually the awk dosent work well with Java runtime.

Comment: `code` df -Pk -h `code`

Solved my all problems. My device name was getting too long so line wrap was getting worse.

Above command help me to get everything in single line and then I cud easily apply java string split logic to extract whatever I wanted. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming name and available space are 1st and 4th columns:

```
 df | awk '{print $1, $4}'
```

Answer (score 1):

the traditional approach would be

```
df | awk '{printf "%-15s%-8s\n",$1,$5}'
```